# Relation between differenciation of a function and its inverse

Tags: derivatives, inverse-function

I came across this question:

> The function $f(x) = e^x + x$ being differentiable and one to one, has a differentiable inverse $f^{-1}(x)$. Find the value of $\frac{d}{dx}(f^{-1})$ at the point $f(log(2))$.

I approached this as:
$$
f^{-1}(f(x)) = x
$$

So,
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(f^{-1}(f(x))) = \frac{d}{dx}(x)
$$

which simplifies to
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(f^{-1}(f(x))) = 1
$$
Hence,
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(f^{-1}(f(log(2)))) = 1
$$

But this does not seem right to me, because it does not matter if I find the derivated of $f^{-1}(f(x))$ at $f(log(2))$ or any other point, neither does it depend on the function, by above reasoning the answer should always be $1$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: $$\frac d{dx}(f(g(x)) \ne \left(\frac d{dx} f\right) (g(x))$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had it fine up till $$\frac{d}{dx}(f^{-1}(f(x))) = 1$$

but then you can't simply plug in $x = \log(2)$ since the value inside the derivative would then be a constant, for which the derivative is $0$. Instead, use the chain rule to get $$f'(x) \cdot (f^{-1})'(f(x)) = 1$$

Then dividing by $f'(x)$, this becomes $$(f^{-1})'(f(x)) = \frac{1}{f'(x)}$$

Now plug in $t = f(x) \to x = f^{-1}(x)$ to get $$(f^{-1})'(t) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(t))}$$

Edit: Since you are already given that the point at which to find the derivative is $f(\log(2))$, you know that $f^{-1}(t) = \log(2)$. Then the derivative at that point would be $$\frac{1}{e^{\log(2)}+1} = \frac{1}{3}$$ since $f'(x) = e^x + 1$

Answer (score 1):

By the chain rule you have $$\frac{d}{dx}(f^{-1}(f(x)))=(f^{-1})'(f(x))f'(x)=1$$

Thus $$(f^{-1})'(f(x))=\frac{1}{f'(x)}=\frac{1}{e^{x}+1}.$$